# Hibernate Multiple Row Set Differing In only one column?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql, persistent-storage

How do I represent similar multiple row data in one hibernate pojo?

For example lets have a table say

```
PKEY  | REFS | UNIQUEID
```

Now I envision a scenario in which I expect multiple REFS for same set of {PKEY, UNIQUEID} values. This will cause multiple rows in the database with same PKEY and UNIQUEID but differing REFS.

In such scenario how do I map that table to my hibernate pojo. Will the following work?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYTABLE")
public class TablePojo
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PKEY")
    int pkey;

    @Column(name = "REFS")
    List<String> refsList;

    @Column(name = "USERID")
    Long userId;

       ..........
       ..........
       ..........
};
```

Comment: You cannot have a multiple rows in a table with the same primary key value. Did you meant foreign key?

Comment: @TomaszBekas Yeah you are right and that automatically answers my questions.... Thanks for bringing it up... I guess its one of those 'blank' moments.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. We all have those blank moments :)